# Passing pointer-to-member-function as pointer-to-function

Tags: c++, callback, sdl

So here's the situation: I'm using C++, SDL and GLConsole in conjunction. I have a class, `SDLGame`, which has the `Init()`, `Loop()`, `Render()` etc - essentially, it holds the logic for my game class.
GLConsole is a nice library so far - it lets me define CVars and such, even inside my SDL class. However, when defining commands, I have to specify a `ConsoleFunc`, which is typedef'd as

```
typedef bool (*ConsoleFunc)( std::vector<std::string> *args);
```

Simple enough. However, like I said, my functions are all in my class, and I know I can't pass pointer-to-class-functions as pointer-to-function arguments. I can't define static functions or make functions outside my class because some of these ConsoleFuncs must access class data members to be useful. I'd like to keep it OOP, since - well, OOP is nice.

Well, I actually have this problem "solved" - but it's extremely ugly. I just have an instance of `SDLGame` declared as an extern variable, and use that in my ConsoleFuncs/main class.

So, the question is: Is there a way to do this that isn't stupid and dumb like the way I am doing it? (Alternatively: is there a console library like GLConsole that supports SDL and can do what I'm describing?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the only interface you have is that function pointer, then you're screwed.

A member function needs a `this` pointer to be called, and if you have no way of passing that, you're out of luck (I guess the `std::vector<std::string>* args` pointer is what you get passed from the library).

In other words, even though that library uses C++ containers, it's not a good C++ library, because it relies on free functions for callbacks. A good C++ library would use `boost::function` or something similar, or would *at the very least* let you pass a `void* user_data` pointer that gets passed through to your callback. If you had that, you could pass the `this` pointer of your class, cast it back inside the callback, and call the appropriate member function.

Comment: Well dang. Thanks anyway. Got any suggestions for another library to use? I was looking at OGLConsole, but it has the exact same problem.

Comment: @user: Sorry, no library suggestion. :/

Comment: I strongly recommend the usage of a `void*` "user data". Sure, it's not as a pretty as a modern language 'delegate', but it is a safe path to take since it is your code that registers the callback and the user data as a pair. So, it is 100% safe to just cast the incoming `void*` to the appropriate class type because the callback is set with that intent in mind.